# Enlaces que traen secciones de la página

Tags: html, css

Estoy creando un menu y quiero consegir que los enlaces que tengo en el menú, de las diferentes secciones de la página web me transporten esas secciones a la pantalla. Esas secciones las tengo "ocultas" y quiero que aparezcan. Pero no consigo hacerlo mediante los enlaces, ¿es posible hacerlo?

Comment: si están ocultas, necesitarás usar javascript para mostrarlas

Comment: Por favor publica lo que tienes de código y se un poco mas claro con lo que necesitas, si puedes con imágenes y demás, para poder darle solución a tu pregunta. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el selector target.

```css
.ocultos div{display:none;}
.ocultos div:target{display:block}
```

```html
<nav><a href="#a">A</a> <a href="#b">B</a> <a href="#c">C</a> <a href="#d">D</a></nav>

<div class="ocultos">
<div id="a">
<p>DIV A: Estoy creando un menu y quiero consegir que los enlaces que tengo en el menú, de las diferentes secciones de la página web me transporten esas secciones a la pantalla. Esas secciones las tengo "ocultas" y quiero que aparezcan. Pero no consigo hacerlo mediante los enlaces, ¿es posible hacerlo?</p>
</div>
<div id="b">
<p>DIV B: Sólo los espejos de azabache de sus ojos son duros cual dos escarabajos de cristal negro. Y el borriquillo se despachaba contra el viento, intentando, inútilmente, arrancar del fango la carreta, al grito sollozante de la chiquilla.</p>
</div>
<div id="c">
<p>DIV C: Come cuanto le doy. Sólo los espejos de azabache de sus ojos son duros cual dos escarabajos de cristal negro. Así no tendrán en su memoria la tristeza de mis maldades, de mis cinismos, de mis impertinencias.</p>
</div>
  <div id="d">
<p>DIV D: Come cuanto le doy. Sólo los espejos de azabache de sus ojos son duros cual dos escarabajos de cristal negro. Así no tendrán en su memoria la tristeza de mis maldades, de mis cinismos, de mis impertinencias.</p>
</div>
</div>
```